# How to create and use static library containing resource like form/dialog in mfc c++?

Tags: c++, mfc

When I am creating a form/dialog in a library project and trying to access its header file in another project, it gives a error that resource ID of that form/dialog is unidentified.

Normal functions created in any class works fine. But when resource/ control is used it gives error.

What can be the mistake? Is there any specific step or point to be done?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error? If you have an error message, copy/paste it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the enumeration that defines the Resource ID from the header file. Include resource.h in the .cpp file for your form. Use the resource ID directly instead of the enum when you pass the ID to the base class in your form's constructor.

```
MyDialog::MyDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(IDD_DIALOG1, pParent)
{

}
```

Comment: On removing the library project does not compile.

Comment: I have completed my answer.